# VirtualEnvWrapper Setup Command Error

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I am setting up Virtualenvwrapper in Windows 8. This is based on the tutorial at -

http://www.newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows

To setup, the author says to run the following:

```
$ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
$ export MSYS_HOME=/c/msys/1.0
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

As far as I know, the above works in Ubuntu. I have tried it personally there. My question is what is the equivalent in Windows?

I am not sure why the author gave the above under Windows setup. It simply won't work for me.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. Simply put, the default Virtualenvwrapper doesn't work well with windows. There is an alternative built called VirtualenvWrapper-Powershell. Search for it on Google.

Using powershell install this and to create any new environment, simply use the command New-VirtualEnvironment TextEnv(replace with whatever name you want to give).

That did a perfect job for me.